# How would one describe physically pressable keyboard keys in a single word?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was thinking about movable/moving keys, but it's possible to confuse that with keys that can be removed from the keyboard and placed on a different one, or in a different position, I'm afraid.

"Physically pressable" doesn't cut it, as the keys already have to be described as simply "pressable" - in the sense that they are interactive.

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure what you are looking for, but what is the problem with "key" itself or "keyboard"?

Comment: All keys on keyboards on computers can be pressed. So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Lambie, I'm not sure, but I think they might have meant digital keyboard vs. physical keyboard, i.e. the different between the computer on my laptop and my phone.

Comment: A physical key is an electrical **switch**. That term is never used for the "virtual" keys or buttons on a touch screen. If they can be removed from the keyboard they are even more like switches – or did you mean the key **tops** can be removed?

Comment: I'd like to see the sentence that you are trying to write.  Is there a single adjective in your native language?

Comment: @ James K "Все клавиши являются подвижными и нажимаются" -> "All keys are movable and can be pressed". The issue is, "подвижными", strictly speaking, translates to "movable", but I feel that the meaning can differ slightly in certain context. And "нажимаются" is "pressable". I can replace it with "all keys are physically pressable", but would rather be as close to the original as possible.

Comment: @Lambie I meant that the keys physically travel. Actually I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many kinds of keyswitch, from plastic membrane, through "tactile" (with a metal dome to give a click), to piezoelectric to
tada!

> "full-travel".

That's a phrase I saw looking through some electronic supplier catalogs. It might be a good starting point for the specification, or as a term for further search.

Comment: This could have worked, but the actual travel distance is much smaller.

Comment: Although just saying that "the keys are pressable and physically travel" is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!